# What was abnormal in Hanna's DNA?

Tags: genetic-engineering, genetics, hanna

In the movie *Hanna* (2011), DNA was manipulated by the CIA to create super-soldiers. In the [this clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ixCNYdjNoc), we see at 00:55 a lab report marked "Abnormal".

In the lower left-hand corner can be seen the words *non-existent, multiple double, Adenine Thymine, and Interfering.* Supposedly Thymine and Adenine form base pairs, but that doesn't appear to be happening here.

What was abnormal about her DNA, and how did it make her stronger and faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This remains a mystery.**
From the script all you get is that Hanna's DNA is manipulated beyond what is possible in the human genome. What it does never gets determined but for what capacities Hanna shows in the movie and of course the expectations Marissa and Erik have.

Some snippets:

> MILITARY DOCTOR 2
>   It’s contaminated. Run it again.

...

> INT. MOROCCAN HOTEL BEDROOM - NIGHT 98
>   The TV flickers illuminating HANNA as she sits on her bed
>   looking at the DNA report folded up into a tight wad. She
>   smooths it out and reads.
>   The test reads: HANNA HELLER - “SGM + test results.
>   Interfering sequence present. Abnormal. B sample confirms
>   result”
>   HANNA stares at the words. “Interfering sequence present.
>   Abnormal.” HANNA looks at the photo of herself and those
>   words.
>   HANNA
>   “Abnormal”
>   What does it mean?

...

> SOPHIE
>   I don’t know. I mean, I don’t
>   really know who you are. Do I?
>   HANNA
>   That’s just it. Neither do I.
>   She reaches into her bag. Brings out the DNA report. Shows it
>   to Sophie. They read. Interfering Sequence. Abnormal.
>   SOPHIE
>   What is it?
>   HANNA
>   It’s something about me. I know
>   what DNA is. I don’t understand the
>   rest of it.

...

> OWNER
>   You’ve never used the internet?
>   HANNA
>   No.
>   He logs in for her and brings up a search engine.
>   OWNER
>   You type whatever you want here,
>   and the internet gives it to you.
>   He types “French mustard cream cheese” and presses SEARCH.
>   OWNER (CONT’D)
>   Make sense?
>   HANNA
>   Makes sense.
>   He walks away as Hanna pecks out a few words: D-N-A I-N-T-E-RF-E-R-I-N-G
>   S-E-Q-U-E-N-C-E. And presses SEARCH.
>   The page fills with text: “An interfering sequence within
>   DNA”, “...intervention into a mother’s uterus during
>   pregnancy.”
>   There’s so much information.
>   Hanna pecks two new words: E-R-I-K H-E-L-L-E-R. Search.

...

> MARISSA (CONT’D)
>   A public computer at a Berlin
>   internet cafe. A search for DNA
>   interfering sequence.

Reference:
http://academy.filminfocus.com/scripts/hanna_screenplay.pdf